# Print a C pointers of a shared memory

Tags: c, pointers, char, shared-memory

I'm new to C and I have a question about char pointers and shared memory and what it will print. Take a look:

```
key_t ke =ftok("./exe","k"); 
int ds_shm=shmget(ke,100,IPC_CREAT|IP_ECXL|0644);
char *p;

if ( ds_shm<0) {   //if the memory alredy exists

    ds_shm=shmget(ke,100,0644); //get the identifier

    p= (char*) shmat(ds_shm,NULL,0);  //p cointain  the address of the shm

} else {  // if not texted create it

    p= (char*) shmat(ds_shm,NULL,0); // p now contain the address
 
    strncpy(p,"hello",sizeof("hello"));  //init

}
```

Now, if I want to see the content my professor does:

```
printf(" Content of shared memory: %s\n" , p);
```

but shouldn't it be using a `*` to access the value of the variable?

```
printf(" Content of shared memory: %s\n" , *p); // ??
```

Comment: Nope, if you dereference the pointer you get the address of the first character

Comment: The expression `*p` is *exactly* equal to `p[0]`. That is, it's the value of the first element, which in your case is a single `char`. It seems you might need to take a step back and study more about basic C pointer usage.

Comment: but for int* p pointer we do  prinf(*p) ? why it doesn't  work?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). It _tells_ you explicitly what you must pass for `%s`, and for `%d`.

Comment: ... and realise that C strings are variable-length, so you can't pass them by value like you can an integer. Hence they're always used via a pointer to the first character.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` tells `printf` “I am passing an `int`. Print it.”

`%s` tells `printf` “I am passing the address of the first character of a string. Get the characters from that address and print them.”